# suse server virtual box issues

Tags: suse

I'm trying to install guest additions but when I'm trying install `./VBoXLinuxAdditions.run` I get "Failed to set up service vboxadd, please `check the log file /var/log/VBoxGuestAdditions.log"` and it is content:

```
vboxadd.sh: failed: modprobe vboxguest failed.
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Usually this is caused when `vboxguest` can not be build on that machine, due to missing components (kernel-headers, compiler etc.). There should be another log file next to VBoxGuestAdditions.log which protocols the build progress. You will find the root cause there.

Additionally you can check out `modinfo vboxguest` and `modprobe vboxguest`, but I am pretty sure it is not available in the system because something like kernel headers are missing.